# How could I duplicate special symbols like ^ ,_?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

If input = 3
Then output,
^___^

## the symbol ^ must be at front and at the last.

## underscore _ number is the input value

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try `'^' + input_val * '_' + '^'`, this should do the job.

Try not to use "input" as a variable since it also is the name of the built-in function to get user inputs, it could prevent future errors.

Comment: Shadowing [builtin functions in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is a bad idea.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? What's wrong about using built-in overloaded operators + and *?

Comment: Using `input` as a variable name. We should correct mistakes made by the OP.